# Anchor drywall edge to ceiling next to a wall running along joist?

Tags: drywall, basement, joists, drywall-anchor

I am working on a wall that will separate the main basement area from the storage area (with a door). This new wall will run along the above floor joist which removes the possibility for drywall anchors. I cannot add blocking there either because it is covered for an air return from the main floor.

The attached image shows a basic view of the proposed wall and where it would run along the joist.

Can I still put drywall up without anchoring this edge? Will the wall's future drywall butting up against the loose ceiling edge be sufficient to anchor it?

[image: Proposed wall along floor joist, shows lack of drywall anchors]

Comment: Why can't you add blocking, it looks like the wall will be directly under a ceiling joist.

Comment: Without the blocking the edge will be subject to motion that will crack the joint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can purchase metal "corner backing"--essentially a sheet metal angle that you attach to your top plate. It's very similar to corner bead, which could probably serve as a substitute, but it doesn't have holes and it's slightly larger. The drywall then screws into that.

Obviously the screws will penetrate the air return, but I don't consider that a problem.

There are also clips like this that you'd slide the ceiling panels into. They'd be oriented opposite of what's shown here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd say just use 2x4s to build what you have sketched in red, then attach the top plate to the joists above. I don't think the air return is much of an issue.

It's not "ideal" but it shouldn't be a problem. In any case it's highly preferable to having drywall sheets just "loose" at the top.